# how to loop tukeyHSD in R

Tags: r

Dear Stackoverflow Users, 
here is an example table, simillar to what I have, only mine has over 1000 protein and here I've placed 2:
    `#for stack overflow#

```
Accession <- rep(c("AT1G01320.1", "AT1G01050.1"), each =14)
Description<- rep(c("protein1", "protein2"), each = 14)
genotype <- c("WT", "WT","WT", "WT", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "ntrc", "ntrc", "ntrc")
genotype <- c("WT", "WT","WT", "WT", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "ntrc", "ntrc", "ntrc")
variable <- c("WT1", "WT2","WT3", "WT4", "m1", "m2", "m3", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "ntrc1", "ntrc2", "ntrc3", "WT1", "WT2","WT3", "WT4", "m1", "m2", "m3", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "ntrc1", "ntrc2", "ntrc3")

value <- c(5535705, 8034106, 4879639, 6817736, 23109581, 3778870, 6020611, 4480108, 6131362, 4210275, 27630841, 4702864,2966520, 9065916,  151903.67, 417423.81, 2895121.80, 810620.92, 822284.83, 6477122.14, 12266704.79, 11196940.77, 12143974.82, 1040832.60, 136497.86, 9294097.54, 506386.62, 32266.71)


prot<- data.frame(Accession, Description, genotype, variable, value)
> prot
 Accession Description genotype variable       value
1  AT1G01320.1    protein1       WT      WT1  5535705.00
2  AT1G01320.1    protein1       WT      WT2  8034106.00
3  AT1G01320.1    protein1       WT      WT3  4879639.00
4  AT1G01320.1    protein1       WT      WT4  6817736.00
5  AT1G01320.1    protein1        m       m1 23109581.00
6  AT1G01320.1    protein1        m       m2  3778870.00
7  AT1G01320.1    protein1        m       m3  6020611.00
8  AT1G01320.1    protein1        f       f1  4480108.00
9  AT1G01320.1    protein1        f       f2  6131362.00
10 AT1G01320.1    protein1        f       f3  4210275.00
11 AT1G01320.1    protein1        f       f4 27630841.00
12 AT1G01320.1    protein1     ntrc    ntrc1  4702864.00
13 AT1G01320.1    protein1     ntrc    ntrc2  2966520.00
14 AT1G01320.1    protein1     ntrc    ntrc3  9065916.00
15 AT1G01050.1    protein2       WT      WT1   151903.67
16 AT1G01050.1    protein2       WT      WT2   417423.81
17 AT1G01050.1    protein2       WT      WT3  2895121.80
18 AT1G01050.1    protein2       WT      WT4   810620.92
19 AT1G01050.1    protein2        m       m1   822284.83
20 AT1G01050.1    protein2        m       m2  6477122.14
21 AT1G01050.1    protein2        m       m3 12266704.79
22 AT1G01050.1    protein2        f       f1 11196940.77
23 AT1G01050.1    protein2        f       f2 12143974.82
24 AT1G01050.1    protein2        f       f3  1040832.60
25 AT1G01050.1    protein2        f       f4   136497.86
26 AT1G01050.1    protein2     ntrc    ntrc1  9294097.54
27 AT1G01050.1    protein2     ntrc    ntrc2   506386.62
28 AT1G01050.1    protein2     ntrc    ntrc3    32266.71
>
```

I want to write a loop that will first subset the original data frame containing >1000 entries into subsets based on single protein ID, than do one way ANOVA and Tukeys HSD, get p adj from Tukeys, than print it into pdf.
so far I have:

```
`IDs<-unique((prot$Accession))
 tukey_fullAA <- list()
 table_fullAA <- NULL

 for (i in 1:length(IDs)){
 temp <- prot[(prot$Accession)==IDs[i],]
 AV<- summary(aov(temp$value ~ temp$genotype))
 tukey_fullAA <- list(TukeyHSD(aov(temp$value ~ temp$genotype)))
 }

 for(j in 1:length(tukey_fullAA))## important loop over whole list
 {
 tukey <- tukey_fullAA[[j]]
 factor_table <- unlist(lapply(tukey, function(x) nrow(x)))
 factor_table <- rep(names(factor_table), factor_table)
 tukey_bound <- NULL
 for (k in 1:length(tukey))
 {
 tukey_bound <- rbind(tukey_bound, tukey[[k]])
 }
 pairs <- rownames(tukey_bound)
 rownames(tukey_bound) <- NULL
 tukey_bound <- as.data.frame(tukey_bound)
 tukey_bound$parameter <- factor_table
 tukey_bound$pairs <- pairs
 table_fullAA <- rbind(table_fullAA, tukey_bound)
 }
```

as it is now it doesn't loop, I struggled to get the Tukey HSD into table, When I have it I want to find the significant values p adj, I get also confused about adding a column that would say what protein are these values for. I imagine it as a column first column containing one name for as many rows as it needs for out put.
thanks a lot!